# How to Rename Google Form's responses in the Google Drive Automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I would like to make a google form where people can upload some files in. But they can choose some or only one to submit, meaning that not all responses are present. Then I want the file to be name as ID_person*'s_*name__paper 1/ paper 2/ paper 3. I have followed some tutorials on internet but it seems it didn't work out. I'm sorry that I am an absolute beginner in coding. Could someone please guide me through the whole process?

Thanks!

var formResponse = form.getResponse;
var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

I have no idea why it says formResponse.getItemResponses is not a function